# Which way you recommend zend lucene search with php or lucene itself and port with php?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, solr, zend-search-lucene

We are in development of a classifieds website, which you might already know that we need a really good search engine. Filtering menu on the left side is a MUST in our project. Anyway, I am asking if we should use zend lucene or we should install lucene server ourselves and connect our search file with its api? I couldnt find any performance/benchmark comparison results and wanted to ask here. I would like to hear your opinions in terms of : limits, advantages,disadanteges ..

Comment: You should provide us with some information concerning volume of entries, languages, and expectations on traffic and rebuild frequency. These factors can play a significant role in a recommendation.

Comment: daily most 10k data entries (say that used car classifieds with lots of properties like model, make, features ..) and about upto 1 billion page views per month.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience Zend Lucene is good for small amounts of data, but slows down very quick as you add more data.  I had to research a new alternative to zend lucene because it's performance just wasn't cutting it on my current project.  To make a long story short, we went with [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which is built on Apache Lucene.  Indexing of 70k + articles went from hours to minutes.

I should add that [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) came in a close second in my decision and would be worth a look.

Comment: Jeff, Sphinx is only text-based solution, in our project; we cant provide a search filter like : cars having "2 door" "4 door" option (multiple fields) thus, i am not using Sphinx. About Solr vs zend; in terms of "limits", actually in our website; there would be daily about max 10k daily data enterance (say classified advertisements) and about up to 1 billion unique view monthly. So we are focusing more of search, not the indexing time. (the indexing will be automated after a advertisement is entered so it is waived into 1 day, not minutes)

Comment: So i am after about the numbers of the searching capacity intead of indexing capacity.

Comment: Well if you're talking those kinds of numbers then do not use the Zend_Lucene solution.  We went from 9 - 10 seconds waiting for search results with Zend_Lucene down to to milliseconds with Solr.  And that was for 70k records.

Comment: I agree with Jeff. To add to the conversation, in my opinion, Solr works best when you're not not bottlenecked by memory constraints. At the end of the day, there's value in indexing your documents in Solr and then load testing the instance with common queries.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) - it will need minimal effort to install and has a [PHP interface](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP). It also has in-built support for [faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) (the filters on the side) and is quite [fast and scalable](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceData).

Comment: Hello! Do you know example performace charts about solr and lucene? because solr is on top of the lucene. I am really between zend lucene, lucene and solr and couldn't decide yet.

Comment: Solr is built on top of Lucene (which is a library and not a search engine) - there is no direct comparison between the two.  You will have to write code to use Lucene which will be very similar to the code that is already there in Solr. I will be very surprised if properly configured Solr is significantly slower than a custom implementation using Lucene. I will recommend that you review the performance that others are getting from Solr and check if it meets your requirements.